# Why is that so many apps today require a MacBook with an M1 chip?

Tags: mac-appstore, apple-silicon, system-requirements

I face this situation so often today. I have a MacBook without an M1 chip, and many simple apps on the AppStore for some reason require it.

As I see this, they don't have any specific use to it, the app is just built in a way that requires an M1 for some reason.

Specifically, I came across the SkyVPN MacOS [client](https://www.skyvpn.net/vpn-for-mac) and was unable to install it. It is obvious that some VPN apps don't need the M1 chip, for example, protonvpn, IVPN, Tunnelbear and others.

Can someone more experienced tell me what is that reason developers require an M1 chip without a reason?

Comment: It’s the platform they chose to support.  Why the dev to compile their apps for M1 and not Intel is entirely their own decision

Comment: As I build apps for Android I know about the difficulty of choosing the right minimum platform level (android version to support)... For VPN clients, it makes no sense to require that chip, as I assume from experience with other vpn apps.. So I thought there was something behind M1 requirement I don't know

Comment: It is called progress, otherwise we would still be running a Mac OS on a 68000 processor.

Comment: Just to be clear, an M1 chip isn't something they have in addition (like a graphics card). It actually means (in this context) that it has an ARM CPU rather than an Intel CPU (and you're finding that Intel CPUs aren't supported)

Comment: Is the link correct? It claims that the Mac version supports MacOS versions from Yosemite to Catalina, all of which are older than M1 and do not support it.

Comment: "*As I build apps for Android*" it's probably more similar to the [native library support](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#specify-abi) rather than the Android version; almost all Android apps support arm but not x86 due to its rarity.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The SkyVPN app you linked to isn't really a "MacOS client".

It's an app that they wrote for iPadOS, which will work on an Apple Silicon Mac.

[image]

M-series Macs can run many apps that were originally designed for iPhone or iPad, because they share the same CPU architecture.

All the apps you're seeing are iPad apps that the developer has allowed to be on the Mac App Store.

To be honest, there's a lot of low-quality apps on the App Store.

I'd say that most apps *actually designed for macOS* will have Universal Binaries for Intel and Apple Silicon.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! So I was inattentive a bit, but I was confused with this for long time with several apps. Well, on the download page linked, they say on a pic: "macos client"

Comment: To be fair, it's probably something more along the lines of the developers seeing that suddenly (since the introduction of the M1) they now have a larger market available for their products at no additional cost to themselves, so why wouldn't they support M1 (but not Intel) Macs?

Comment: Because M1 can run iPadOS apps, but supporting x64 would require porting the whole app for macOS. For apps running natively on macOS supporting both CPU architectures doesn't need any extra work.